# ElasticSearch/Lucene query string — select "field X exists"

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

How do I query ElasticSearch through Kibana to select items that have field X?

For example, I have a mapping with fields `{"a": {"type": "string"}, "b": {"type": "string"}}`, and two documents

```
{"a": "lalala"}
{"a": "enoheo", "b": "nthtnhnt"}
```

I want to find the second document without knowing what its `b` actually is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [exists filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html), like:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "filter": {
        "exists": {
           "field": "b"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you need a Lucene query-string query, this should do it:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "b:*"
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/ad336a0888a279bfdace03e217bf1915adbf0fe2

Comment: I want it to work with Kibana with the Lucene query string, not the query DSL.

Comment: What about the negative case? How would you use the lucene query-string to test that a field does not exist?

Comment: For the negative case, putting a minus in front of the query seems to work: "-b:*"

Answer (score 13):

It's been a while since these answers were given. In case anyone needs a more updated answer, the docs now give this example for selecting results that have a certain field.

In query-string syntax:

> where the field `title` has any non-null value:
>
> ```
> _exists_:title
> ```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names